bb-plugin upgrade broke the site
bb-plugin upgrade 2.8.3.8 -> 2.8.4 ended up breaking the site.
2024/10/04 09:39:43 [error] 3503526#3503526: *1928276 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'FLBuilderGlobalStyles' not found in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/modules/button/button.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/modules/button/includes/frontend.css.php(80): FLButtonModule->use_default_border()
#1 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/classes/class-fl-builder.php(3430): include('/var/www/html/w...')
#2 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/classes/class-fl-builder.php(742): FLBuilder::render_css(true)
#3 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/classes/class-fl-builder.php(660): FLBuilder::enqueue_layout_cached_asset('css', false)
#4 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/classes/class-fl-builder.php(565): FLBuilder::enqueue_layout_styles_scripts()
#5 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): FLBuilder::enqueue_all_layouts_styles_scripts('')

Does anybody else have the same issue?
Thanks

Revert to an older version.

Same, it's not the first time. My company is now looking for another solution: they dont deserve the money we gave.
